# Code coverage of Vue files in Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, code-coverage, webpacker

In existing Rails+Vue.js (with webpacker) project we have plenty of feature tests (Capybara tests).

At the moment we can only see code coverage of ruby code.

Is there a way to setup code coverage for Vue/Javascript code without writing JS based tests from scratch?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007695/rails-capybara-webkit-javascript-code-coverage

Comment: I think that setting this up with Webpacker&Vue is probably way more complex. Since this is pretty common combination of technologies I would love to hear if someone managed to solve this ...